# How to call a method with parameters from another class in java?

Tags: java

I am coming to a problem where I want to call a method from one class to another, but this method has a parameters. I tried doing `String searchData = "searchValue"` from my another class, but it for my other class is not being called.

Here is my code:

**The method that I want to call**

```
public List<JobSearchItem> getJobAutocomplete(String searchValue) {
    String sValue = "%" + searchValue.toUpperCase() + "%";
    return dataUtilityService.getJdbcTemplate().query(SQL_GET_JOB_SEARCH_LISTS, 
                                new Object[]{sValue, sValue}, jobSearchItemMapper);
}
```

**the other method that I want to call the above code**

```
public void loadSearchList() throws SQLException, NamingException, URISyntaxException, IOException, ParseException {

   String searchData = "searchValue";
  List<JobSearchItem> jobSearchList = XPayService.getJobAutocomplete(searchData);


    this.setJobSearchItems(jobSearchList);
}
```

Comment: Either your method should be `static` or the calling class must have an instance of the class that the method belong to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need an instance of the `XPayService` class to call the method on, or else you can make the method static

**Using an instance of the class:**

```
class XPayService() {
    public List<JobSearchItem> getJobAutocomplete(String searchValue) {
        String sValue = "%" + searchValue.toUpperCase() + "%";
        return dataUtilityService.getJdbcTemplate().query(SQL_GET_JOB_SEARCH_LISTS, 
                                    new Object[]{sValue, sValue}, jobSearchItemMapper);
    }
}

public void loadSearchList() throws SQLException, NamingException, URISyntaxException, IOException, ParseException {
    XPayService xps = new XPayService();
    String searchData = "searchValue";
    List<JobSearchItem> jobSearchList = xps.getJobAutocomplete(searchData);
    this.setJobSearchItems(jobSearchList);
}
```

**Using a static method:**

```
class XPayService() {
    public static List<JobSearchItem> getJobAutocomplete(String searchValue) {
        String sValue = "%" + searchValue.toUpperCase() + "%";
        return dataUtilityService.getJdbcTemplate().query(SQL_GET_JOB_SEARCH_LISTS, 
                                    new Object[]{sValue, sValue}, jobSearchItemMapper);
    }
}

public void loadSearchList() throws SQLException, NamingException, URISyntaxException, IOException, ParseException {
    String searchData = "searchValue";
    List<JobSearchItem> jobSearchList = XPayService.getJobAutocomplete(searchData);
    this.setJobSearchItems(jobSearchList);
}
```

Comment: Can you please check out my other question for more information. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54659439/how-to-filter-jquery-autocomplete-in-java  .. I am trying to call the method for my autocomplete to work, also I tried the code above of yours and did not work. Is it maybe "searchValue"?

Comment: My code answers the question: `How to call a method with parameters from another class in java?` -- It doesn't necessarily fix your problems, but based on the information in this question, it should answer your question

Comment: Ok. But, can you check out my other question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54659439/how-to-filter-jquery-autocomplete-in-java and help me solve it

Comment: The issue is that it's very hard for me to test your code considering I don't have any html/js/database/java code other than what's inside your question. I don't have anything to execute or run, so you should consider re-writing your question and following this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for the help